# How to get the class variables count of a given.java file?

Tags: java, reflection

I need to create an application to get the class variables(attributes) count on a given .java file.So I developed a code using java reflection as below.So in here I create a new .java file with the same content of importing .java file in my src package because then that .java file can be accessible to the reflection purposes.But the problem is IDE is not figuring out the updates of that files automatically,which means even though the file is created already in my directory IDE doesn't figure it out instantly so I need to refresh the src package to notify the updates to the IDE.So how can I solve this issue.Therefor when you run this for first time there will be an exception of class not found exception ,because even though that .java file already there in the src folder IDE doesn't know.
I tried  with eclipse, Intelij IDES.

```
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.FileWriter;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.lang.reflect.Field;
  importjava.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


 public class AppInitializer {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                meth ();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ( );
            }
        }
    });

    FileReader fr=new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Sample.java");
    int i;
    StringBuffer str= new StringBuffer("");
    while((i=fr.read())!=-1){
    str.append ( (char)i );}

    String s = String.valueOf ( str );


    String replaceString=s.replaceAll ( "public class [^\\n]+", "public class filename{" );
    System.out.println (replaceString );

    fr.close();
    try {
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("src/filename.java");
        myWriter.write( String.valueOf ( replaceString ) );

        myWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
 static void meth() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Class classs= Class.forName ( "filename" );
    int count = 0;
    for (Field field : classs.getDeclaredFields ()){
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println (count );
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Do you generate a new `java` file while the program is running and want to count the fields of that, but the IDE doesn't realise that the file is there?

Comment: @Schred Exactly

Comment: @Schred do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you compiling it into a class? The `java` file is just the source code for a class that doesn't exist yet. You have to compile it before your program can work with it.

Comment: 1. Why are you performing a significant part of your work inside a shutdown hook instead of just after the other code? 2. Don’t initialize a `StringBuffer` with an empty string like `new StringBuffer("")`, just use the default constructor. 3. There is no reason to use `String.valueOf(str)` instead of `str.toString()`, even less for using `String.valueOf(replaceString)` instead of just `replaceString` which is already a `String`. 4. Generally, reading a file byte for byte is the most inefficient way to read a file.

Comment: 5. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to open read or write and finally close a file. 6. As said in the answer, a `.java` source code file can not get loaded like a compiled `.class` file.

Comment: Besides… why do you think, renaming the class will change the number of declared fields? Why don’t you try to get the declared fields directly from `Sample.java`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just add a new `.java` file to your program, that doesn't add a new class to it. You have to compile it at runtime in order for the `Class.forName(...)` method to be able to find it.

For a guide on how to do that, see [this tutorial](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/04/03/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and-9/).

Comment: Yeah, but when I refresh the idea and run it again then the expected output will be display.

Comment: Please check if the IDE generates a `.class` file for the `.java` file while compiling.